# Trying to set variable from while read loop header to var

Tags: bash, base64

I am trying to set a variable from my while loop to itself. I've looked around a lot and tested various methods but haven't been able to get anything to work.

```
while read ip port srv ban
do
rm -f certificate.crt     #sterilizing 
echo -e "$ban" | base64 -d | dos2unix | openssl x509 -inform d > certificate.crt
sleep .5
cert=$(openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout)
echo "$cert"
$ban = $cert
done < outfiles.txt
```

Here's what outfiles.txt looks like with a one line snippet.

```
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx 443 X509 MIIE/zCCA+egAwIBAgIEUdNARDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBsDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUVudHJ1c3QsIEluYy4xOTA3BgNVBAsTMHd3dy5lbnRydXN0Lm5ldC9DUFMgaXMgaW5jb3Jwb3JhdGVkIGJ5IHJlZmVyZW5jZTEfMB0GA1UECxMWKGMpIDIwMDYgRW50cnVzdCwgSW5jLjEtMCsGA1UEAxMkRW50cnVzdCBSb290IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MB4XDTE0MDkyMjE3MTQ1N1oXDTI0MDkyMzAxMzE1M1owgb4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1FbnRydXN0LCBJbmMuMSgwJgYDVQQLEx9TZWUgd3d3LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L2xlZ2FsLXRlcm1zMTkwNwYDVQQLEzAoYykgMjAwOSBFbnRydXN0LCBJbmMuIC0gZm9yIGF1dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxMjAwBgNVBAMTKUVudHJ1c3QgUm9vdCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eSAtIEcyMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuoS2ctueDGvimekwAad26jK4lUEaydphTlhyz/72gnm/c2EGCqUn2LNf00VOHHLWTjLycooP94MZ0GqAgABFHrDH55q/ElcnHKNoLwqHvWprDl5l8xx31dSFjXAhtLMy54ui1YY5ArG40kfO5MlJxDun3vtUfVe+8OhuwnmyOgtV4lCYFjITXC94VsHClLPyWuQnmp8k18bs0JslguPMwsRFxYyXegZrKhGfqQpuSDtv29QRGUL3jwe/9VNfnD70FyzmaaxOMkxid+q36OW7NLwZi66cUee3frVTsTMi5W3PcDwa+uKbZ7aD9I2lr2JMTeBYrGQ0EgP4to2UYySkcQIDAQABo4IBDzCCAQswDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQEwMwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEJzAlMCMGCCsGAQUFBzABhhdodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5lbnRydXN0Lm5ldDAzBgNVHR8ELDAqMCigJqAkhiJodHRwOi8vY3JsLmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L3Jvb3RjYTEuY3JsMDsGA1UdIAQ0MDIwMAYEVR0gADAoMCYGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhpodHRwOi8vd3d3LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L0NQUzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUanImetAe733nO2lR1GyNn5ASZqswHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUaJDkZ6SmU4DHhmak8fdLQ/uEvW0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAGkzg/woem99751V68U+ep11s8zDODbZNKIoaBjqHmnTvefQd9q4AINOSs9v0fHBIj905PeYSZ6btp7h25h3LVY0sag82f3Azce/BQPUAsXx5cbaCKUTx2IjEdFhMB1ghEXveajGJpOkt800uGnFE/aRs8lFc3a2kvZ2ClvhA0e36SlMkTIjN0qcNdh4/R0f5IOJJICtt/nP5F2l1HHEhVtwH9s/HAHrGkUmMRTMZb9n3srMM2XlQZHXN75BGpad5oqXnafOrE6aPb0BoGrZTyIAi0TVaWJ7LuvMuueSfWlnPfy4fN5Bh9Bp6roKGHoalUOzeXEodm2h+1dK7E3IDhA=
```

I'm trying to decode the cert, which I can do but I'm trying to replace (overwrite) the encoded certificate with the decoded certificate from the file I'm reading from on each line I go though by setting the $ban variable from `while read ip port srv ban` to the $cert variable.

So when looking at the outfiles.txt you should se

```
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx 443 Certificate: Data: Version: 3 (0x2) Serial Number: 1372799044 (0x51d34044) Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption Issuer: C=US, O=Entrust, Inc., OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is incorporated by reference, OU=(c) 2006 Entrust, Inc., CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority Validity Not Before: Sep 22 17:14:57 2014 GMT Not After : Sep 23 01:31:53 2024 GMT Subject: C=US, O=Entrust, Inc., OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only, CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2 Subject Public Key Info: Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption Public-Key: (2048 bit) Modulus: 00:ba:84:b6:72:db:9e:0c:6b:e2:99:e9:30:01:a7: 76:ea:32:b8:95:41:1a:c9:da:61:4e:58:72:cf:fe: f6:82:79:bf:73:61:06:0a:a5:27:d8:b3:5f:d3:45: 4e:1c:72:d6:4e:32:f2:72:8a:0f:f7:83:19:d0:6a: 80:80:00:45:1e:b0:c7:e7:9a:bf:12:57:27:1c:a3: 68:2f:0a:87:bd:6a:6b:0e:5e:65:f3:1c:77:d5:d4: 85:8d:70:21:b4:b3:32:e7:8b:a2:d5:86:39:02:b1: b8:d2:47:ce:e4:c9:49:c4:3b:a7:de:fb:54:7d:57: be:f0:e8:6e:c2:79:b2:3a:0b:55:e2:50:98:16:32: 13:5c:2f:78:56:c1:c2:94:b3:f2:5a:e4:27:9a:9f: 24:d7:c6:ec:d0:9b:25:82:e3:cc:c2:c4:45:c5:8c: 97:7a:06:6b:2a:11:9f:a9:0a:6e:48:3b:6f:db:d4: 11:19:42:f7:8f:07:bf:f5:53:5f:9c:3e:f4:17:2c: e6:69:ac:4e:32:4c:62:77:ea:b7:e8:e5:bb:34:bc: 19:8b:ae:9c:51:e7:b7:7e:b5:53:b1:33:22:e5:6d: cf:70:3c:1a:fa:e2:9b:67:b6:83:f4:8d:a5:af:62: 4c:4d:e0:58:ac:64:34:12:03:f8:b6:8d:94:63:24: a4:71 Exponent: 65537 (0x10001) X509v3 extensions: X509v3 Key Usage: critical Certificate Sign, CRL Sign X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical CA:TRUE, pathlen:1 Authority Information Access: OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.entrust.net X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: Full Name: URI:http://crl.entrust.net/rootca1.crl X509v3 Certificate Policies: Policy: X509v3 Any Policy CPS: http://www.entrust.net/CPS X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 6A:72:26:7A:D0:1E:EF:7D:E7:3B:69:51:D4:6C:8D:9F:90:12:66:AB X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: keyid:68:90:E4:67:A4:A6:53:80:C7:86:66:A4:F1:F7:4B:43:FB:84:BD:6D Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption 69:33:83:fc:28:7a:6f:7d:ef:9d:55:eb:c5:3e:7a:9d:75:b3: cc:c3:38:36:d9:34:a2:28:68:18:ea:1e:69:d3:bd:e7:d0:77: da:b8:00:83:4e:4a:cf:6f:d1:f1:c1:22:3f:74:e4:f7:98:49: 9e:9b:b6:9e:e1:db:98:77:2d:56:34:b1:a8:3c:d9:fd:c0:cd: c7:bf:05:03:d4:02:c5:f1:e5:c6:da:08:a5:13:c7:62:23:11: d1:61:30:1d:60:84:45:ef:79:a8:c6:26:93:a4:b7:cd:34:b8: 69:c5:13:f6:91:b3:c9:45:73:76:b6:92:f6:76:0a:5b:e1:03: 47:b7:e9:29:4c:91:32:23:37:4a:9c:35:d8:78:fd:1d:1f:e4: 83:89:24:80:ad:b7:f9:cf:e4:5d:a5:d4:71:c4:85:5b:70:1f: db:3f:1c:01:eb:1a:45:26:31:14:cc:65:bf:67:de:ca:cc:33: 65:e5:41:91:d7:37:be:41:1a:96:9d:e6:8a:97:9d:a7:ce:ac: 4e:9a:3d:bd:01:a0:6a:d9:4f:22:00:8b:44:d5:69:62:7b:2e: eb:cc:ba:e7:92:7d:69:67:3d:fc:b8:7c:de:41:87:d0:69:ea: ba:0a:18:7a:1a:95:43:b3:79:71:28:76:6d:a1:fb:57:4a:ec:
```

4d:c8:0e:10

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$ban = $cert
```

with

```
ban=$cert
```

$ is only used to retrieve the value of a variable, not to set a variable.